# Is it possible to make a self balancing robot using small or medium scale integrated circuits?

Tags: control, pid

Almost all the information I've seen about self-balancing robots implies the use of an Arduino to implement the control. I'm wondering if it is possible to implement the control using just small or middle scale integrated circuits such as Operational Amplifiers, Multiplexors, Logic Gates, etc.

As far as I know, the self-balancing robot control system is based on PID control algorithms and I've seen that it is possible to implement an integrator and a differentiator using Operational Amplifiers, is it achievable to make a PID controller for the self-balancing robot using this? Any suggestions on how to?

Comment: it is not an outrageous goal, so it is entirely possible ... did you really want to ask a question that has a yes or no answer?

Comment: I believe they did this before computers were a real thing and I believe they used amplifiers, resistors, capacitors and inductors.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but not practical

Comment: I've found the main problem would be to have the analog info about the tilt angle as I haven't found an analog IMU sensor yet. Using a digital one and then using an analog controller based on Oparationals would be overkill.

Comment: It is not an mcu fault that makes Arduino board that large.